# Calculating Sum and average in SSRS

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I a problem in my report.
I have a matrix which goes like this

---

```
                     |ID   |         
 |Question(TEXT)|    |Point(Value)|   |Calculated(Average)|   |Calculated(Satisfaction)%|
                  Summary:            |Average(Average)   |   |Average(Satisfaction)%|
```

---

This matrix is inside another group which is a page group.

So, my question is in one of the Page groups,

The Question_Text is blank and in tern all the point(Values) are 0.

The average as per the row is showing correct value but the summary average does not show correct as it is also considering that extra row and calculating the average.

So if sum of all averages is 40 and there are 4 questions (including blank Question)
the average would be 10 instead of 13.33 as it divides by 4 instead of 3.

That row is displayed due to the query , so do I need to change the query or is there a way I can do it in SSRS itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an expression like this for the excluding the blank questions:

```
=Avg(IIf(Fields!Question_Text.Value = "" or IsNothing(Fields!Question_Text.Value)
  , Nothing
  , Fields!Point_Value.Value))
```

Or an alternative:

```
=Sum(Fields!Point_Value.Value)
  / Sum(IIf(Fields!Question_Text.Value = "" or IsNothing(Fields!Question_Text.Value), 0.0, 1.0))'Updated
```

**Edit after comment:**

I added the expressions into a report - the first worked fine and the second worked fine too after a minor update (see edit details).

I created a test Dataset with the following query:

```
select Question_Group = 'Group1', Question_Text = 'Q1', Point_Value = 10
union all select Question_Group = 'Group1', Question_Text = 'Q2', Point_Value = 15
union all select Question_Group = 'Group1', Question_Text = 'Q3', Point_Value = 15
union all select Question_Group = 'Group1', Question_Text = '', Point_Value = 0
union all select Question_Group = 'Group2', Question_Text = 'Q4', Point_Value = 10
union all select Question_Group = 'Group2', Question_Text = 'Q5', Point_Value = 15
union all select Question_Group = 'Group2', Question_Text = 'Q6', Point_Value = 15
union all select Question_Group = 'Group2', Question_Text = null, Point_Value = 0
```

I just created a Group based on `Question_Group` and added both expressions to the Group Footer.

Report in Design Mode:

[image]

Report result based on above Dataset:

[image]

Comment: It works for me based on a sample Dataset; please see above. If it's still not working for you and you need further assistance please supply more information on your Dataset and a query to populate some sample data as in the example above.